# How can I use JRE 1.8 with Eclipse Neon?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Trying to run Eclipse Neon I'm getting this error:

```
To open “Eclipse” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.
```

Instead of the legacy JRE, I have already installed JRE 1.8 from Oracle:

```
➜  /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version

java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

However, I can also see it is not available in the path:

```
➜  java -v
No Java runtime present, requesting install.

➜  /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.

➜  ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS you must install the full **JDK** to get complete Java support. The JRE is not sufficient as it only installs the browser plugins.

The current download for the JDK is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: Indeed. Thanks to Oracle for offering a JRE that does not contain a JRE...