# Eclipse won't open with Version 1.8 JVM on Macbook?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse on my Macbook Pro and it asked me to download Version 1.8 of the JVM that was updated on January 17th of this year. I downloaded it off of the official Java website, but when I tried to open Eclipse again, it still wouldn't allow me to open. All this while the Java website is verifying that I have Java installed on my computer.

I don't understand what is wrong with Eclipse, and why it won't open. Can anyone help me install Eclipse on my computer correctly? If you need any more information, ask.

Comment: Do you see an error message when you attempt to open Eclipse? If so, what does it say?

Comment: You have probably installed the JRE - on macOS you must use the full JDK to get complete Java support - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43042219/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 I really appreciate the reply, but when I tried to download the JDK, my Mac told me that it can't write the file, even after it was fully downloaded. The error message says that the file is still being downloaded, even after it finished downloading. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what that means, it installs fine here.